# how to join multiple tables with same column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tables having a column with names date and point and a table of name date and column date I want to join them and display their data in HTML table.
Until now I have done:-

```
    $sql = "SELECT date.date,arabcountry.point,delhidarbar.point,delhiking.point,delhinight.point,disawar.point,faridabad.point,gaziabad.point,lucky7.point,mayapuri.point,peshawar.point,taj.point
FROM date JOIN arabcountry ON date.date = arabcountry.date JOIN delhidarbar ON date.date=delhidarbar.date JOIN delhiking ON date.date=delhiking.date JOIN delhinight ON date.date=delhinight.date JOIN disawar ON date.date=disawar.date JOIN faridabad ON date.date=faridabad.date JOIN gaziabad ON date.date=gaziabad.date JOIN lucky7 ON date.date=lucky7.date JOIN mayapuri ON date.date=mayapuri.date JOIN peshawar ON date.date=peshawar.date JOIN taj ON date.date=taj.date
ORDER BY date.date DESC LIMIT 30";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['date'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'] .'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    };
```

But all I am getting in PHP array is two column with name date and point, point is only of first tabel other tables points are not there.

Comment: Can you rewrite the question, please? Just the question, not all the explanation. I can't understand the part: _point is only of first tabel other tables points are not there._

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases `as` in query. For example

```
SELECT delhidarbar.point as points1, delhiking.point as points2, delhinight.point  as points3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the alias name for each fields, just like below

```
$sql = "SELECT date.date,arabcountry.point as 'a_point',delhidarbar.point as 'del_point',delhiking.point as 'delhike_point',delhinight.point  as 'delhin_point',disawar.point as 'disawar_point'.....";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['date'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['a_point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['del_point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['delhike_point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['delhin_point'].'</strong></td>';
    echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['disawar_point'].'</strong></td>....';

    };
```